# What is the difference between router.route.get() and router.get()?

Tags: node.js, express

What are the advantages of using router.route.get over router.get?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this example from the docs..

```
router.route('/book')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Get a random book');
  })
  .post(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Add a book');
  })
  .put(function(req, res) {
    res.send('Update the book');
  });
```

If you would need to write it with `router.get()` i would look like:

```
router.get("/book", () => {...})
router.post("/book",() => {...})
router.put("/book", () => {...})
```

> Because the path is specified at a single location, creating modular routes is helpful, as is reducing redundancy and typos